# Vectorize code in function where loops use range in Python/NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, vectorization, array-broadcasting

I have a function which is called many times in other functions. To improve computation I am trying to vectorize the code though I did not manage to do so in this particular case in which there are complex ranges involved. Does any of you see how it can be done in this specific case?

```
def growdh_no_bloom(mx, mn, daylen, baset):

    if mn == 0:
        mn = 0.01
    if mx == mn:
        mx += 0.01
    dt = mx - mn

    idl = int(np.floor(daylen))

    # calculate day time hourly temperatures
    t = np.zeros(24)
    t[0] = mn

    for hour in range(1, idl+1):
        t[hour] = dt * np.sin(np.pi/(daylen+4)*(hour)) + mn

    # calculate sunset time and temperature
    ts1 = dt*np.sin(np.pi/(daylen+4)*daylen) + mn
    if ts1 <= 0:
        ts1 = 0.01

    # calculate hourly temperatures (nighttime)
    count = 0
    for hour in range(idl + 1, 24):
        count += 1
        t[hour] = ts1-(ts1-mn)/(np.log(24-daylen))*np.log(count)

    # growing degree hours
    gdhour = 0
    for hour in range(0, 24):
        if t[hour] - baset > 0:
            gdhour += (t[hour] - baset)
    return gdhour
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, I can see it in the if statements, will fix it ASAP

Answer (score 3):

```
from numba import jit
sig = np.random.randn(44100)
import numpy as np

vectorized = jit(growdh_no_bloom)
```

Or simply put

```
import numba
import random

@numba.njit()
def growdh_no_bloom:
    for i in range(): #your for loop with range
```

> Numba is an open-source JIT compiler that translates a subset of
>   Python and NumPy into fast machine code using LLVM, via the llvmlite
>   Python package. It offers a range of options for parallelising Python
>   code for CPUs and GPUs, often with only minor code changes.

[Numba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numba)

In the case of this exception:

```
NumbaWarning: Compilation is falling back to object mode WITHOUT looplifting enabled because Function 'growdh_no_bloom' failed type inference due to: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'numba.dispatcher.LiftedLoop'>
```

Get:

```
numba.__version__
```

if it is 0.44.0 or later

```
pip install --upgrade numba==0.43.1
```

Comment: Thanks for the rapid comment! I am trying to implement @jit in my functions, though I keep getting the NumbaWarning: Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "main_function" failed type inference due to: Untyped global name 'called_function': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>. 

And the corresponding error message: RuntimeError: Failed in object mode pipeline (step: object mode frontend)
Failed in object mode pipeline (step: object mode backend)
LLVM IR parsing error.

Comment: You are welcome, could you please write `@numba.njit()` top of your function and let me know about the result or warning and also its performance.

Comment: Yes I did this, maybe the problem is that the function is being called by another function, which is in turn being called by another function, which is calculated in a dask environment with dask.delayed. I also tried implementing njit and jit in the other functions as well, but the same error message keeps coming up.

Comment: @RensVermeltfoort If you are working with big data and need to chunk it please use: `numba.jit(nogil=True, nopython=True, cache=True)`

Comment: @RensVermeltfoort Also please do it: `numba.jit(forceobj=True)` from here https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4461

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions! In all cases the same message is coming up.

Comment: NumbaWarning: 
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function growdh_no_bloom failed at nopython mode lowering due to: 'growdh_no_bloom'
  numba.jit(forceobj=True)
NumbaWarning: 
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITHOUT looplifting enabled because Function 'growdh_no_bloom' failed type inference due to: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'numba.dispatcher.LiftedLoop'>

File "growdh_no_bloom.py", line 31:
def growdh_no_bloom(mx, mn, daylen, baset):
    <>
    t[0] = mn
    for hour in range(1, idl+1):
    ^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214987/discussion-between-mahsa-hassankashi-and-rens-vermeltfoort).

Comment: `numba` does not have thr full flexibility of python/nnumpy.  Use it selectively

Answer (score 2):

While Numba will definitely yield better performance, I think that a streamlined function will be of use to you as well, for future reference. Note how I removed all of the loops with simple broadcasting.

```
def growdh_no_bloom(mx, mn, daylen, baset):
    mn = 0.01 if mn==0 else mn
    mx = mx + 0.01 if mx == mn else mx
    dt = mx - mn
    idl = int(np.floor(daylen))

    # calculate day time hourly temperatures
    t = np.zeros(24)
    t[0] = mn
    t[1:idl+1] = dt * np.sin(np.pi/(daylen+4)*np.arange(1,idl+1)) + mn

    # calculate sunset time and temperature
    ts1 = dt*np.sin(np.pi/(daylen+4)*daylen) + mn
    ts1 = 0.01 if ts1 <= 0 else ts1

    # calculate hourly temperatures (nighttime)
    t[idl+1:24] = ts1-(ts1-mn)/(np.log(24-daylen))*np.log(np.arange(1,24-idl))

    gdhour = t-baset
    return gdhour[gdhour>0].sum()
```